# error not found value spark import spark.implicits._ import spark.sql

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hbase

I am using  **hadoop 2.7.2 , hbase 1.4.9, spark 2.2.0, scala 2.11.8 and java 1.8** on a *hadoop cluster* which is composed of one master and two slave.

when I run **spark-shel**l after starting the cluster , it works fine.
**I am trying to connect to hbase using scala** by following this tutorial : [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gGwB0kCcdu0][1]  .

But when I try like he does to run the spark-shell by adding those jars like argument I have this error:

> spark-shell  --jars
>   "hbase-annotations-1.4.9.jar,hbase-common-1.4.9.jar,hbase-protocol-1.4.9.jar,htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar,zookeeper-3.4.6.jar,hbase-client-1.4.9.jar,hbase-hadoop2-compat-1.4.9.jar,metrics-json-3.1.2.jar,hbase-server-1.4.9.jar"

```
<console>:14: error: not found: value spark
       import spark.implicits._
              ^
<console>:14: error: not found: value spark
       import spark.sql
              ^
```

and after that even I log out and run spark-shell another time I have the same issue.
Can any one tell me please what is the cause and how to fix it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your import statement `spark` should be an object of type `SparkSession`. That object should have been created previously for you. Or you need to create it yourself (read spark docs). I didn't watch your tutorial video.

The point is it doesn't have to be called `spark`. It could be for instance called `sparkSession` and then you can do `import sparkSession.implicits._`